# Internal EBCDIC support for ANTLR 3.1.3?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, ebcdic

I'm trying to use ANTLR 3.1.3 on a system with local EBCDIC char set

Even a simple grammar like this:

```
lexer grammar test;

GENERIC_ID
: (LETTER)*
;

fragment LETTER
: 'a' .. 'z'
;
```

results in these errors during the initial compile (java org.antlr.Tool test.g):

```
error(10):  internal error: problem parsing group <unknown>: line 1:1: unexpected char: 0x7 : line 1:1: unexpected char: 0x7
org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.GroupLexer.nextToken(GroupLexer.java:233)
antlr.TokenBuffer.fill(TokenBuffer.java:69)
antlr.TokenBuffer.LA(TokenBuffer.java:80)
antlr.LLkParser.LA(LLkParser.java:52)
antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:210)
org.antlr.stringtemplate.language.GroupParser.group(GroupParser.java:120)
org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup.parseGroup(StringTemplateGroup.java:792)
org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup.<init>(StringTemplateGroup.java:274)
org.antlr.stringtemplate.PathGroupLoader.loadGroup(PathGroupLoader.java:67)
org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup.loadGroup(StringTemplateGroup.java:969)
org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup.loadGroup(StringTemplateGroup.java:955)
org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadTemplates(CodeGenerator.java:198)
org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.genRecognizer(CodeGenerator.java:292)
org.antlr.Tool.generateRecognizer(Tool.java:607)
org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:429)
org.antlr.Tool.main(Tool.java:91)
error(10):  internal error: test.g : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find template outputFile.st; group hierarchy is [null]
org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup.lookupTemplate(StringTemplateGroup.java:507)
org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup.getInstanceOf(StringTemplateGroup.java:392)
org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplateGroup.getInstanceOf(StringTemplateGroup.java:404)
org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.genRecognizer(CodeGenerator.java:314)
org.antlr.Tool.generateRecognizer(Tool.java:607)
org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:429)
org.antlr.Tool.main(Tool.java:91)
```

the grammar file seems to be processed appropriately, but it appears something internal is causing some problems.  No matter what chars I use in the grammar file, the illegal char always seems to be 0x7.

Can I not compile ANTLR on a system with local EBCDIC char set?  Any suggestions?

Update:  it appears the problem lies in the template files (.stg files).  If I convert the files in the codegen/templates directory to EBCDIC (also ANTLRCore.sti) then the compilation seems to complete.  Is there a way to tell java/antlr to not read these files in local encoding?  Either that or are these template files available in other encodings?  Otherwise I am forced to convert by hand and replace each one