# Are there ANTLR .stg template files available in different encodings?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, ebcdic

I am trying to generate ANTLR (3.1.3) files on a local EBCDIC charset system.  It appears the template files are in ASCII encoding.  Do I have to convert all the template files by hand?
Do I only need to worry about the files in the following locations:  codegen\templates and tool\templates?

Not converting these files results in errors seen in related question: [internal ebcdic support for antlr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031651/internal-ebcdic-support-for-antlr-3-1-3)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there aren't template files in different encodings. You'll have to do that yourself.